# Braided lobsters

Tags: gr.group-theory, order-theory, universal-algebra, braid-groups, ordered-groups

If $(X,m)$ is a median algebra, then for each $x\in X$, define an operation $\wedge_{x}$ by letting $y\wedge_{x}z=m(x,y,z)$. Then $(X,\wedge_{x})$ is a meet-semilattice with least element $x$. Define the ordering $\leq_{x}$ on $X$ where $y\leq_{x}z$ iff $y=y\wedge_{x}z=m(x,y,z)$. An unrooted lobster is a median algebra $(X,m)$ where if $x,y\in X$, then the interval $([x,y],\leq_{x})$ is a linear ordering. We say that a median algebra $(X,m)$ is non-linear if there does not exist a linear ordering $\leq$ where $m(x,y,z)=(x\wedge y)\vee(x\wedge z)\vee(y\wedge z)$ for all $x,y,z$ and $\wedge,\vee$ are the lattice operations on $(X,\leq)$.

A left lobster group is a structure $(G,m)$ where $G$ is a group, $m$ is a median algebra operation on $G$ that makes $(G,m)$ into a lobster, and where 
$r\cdot m(x,y,z)=m(r\cdot x,r\cdot y,r\cdot z)$ for all $r,x,y,z\in G$. A two-sided lobster group is a left-lobster group $(G,m)$ where $m(x,y,z)\cdot r=m(x\cdot r,y\cdot r,z\cdot r)$ for all $r,x,y,z\in G$.

Can the braid group $B_{n}$ for $n>2,n\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{\infty\}$ be endowed with a ternary operation $m$ so that $(B_{n},m)$ is a non-linear left-lobster group or perhaps even a two-sided lobster group? Can the pure braid group $PB_{n}$ for $n>2,n\in\mathbb{N}\cup\{\infty\}$ be endowed with a ternary operation $m$ so that $(PB_{n},m)$ is a non-linear left-lobster group or perhaps even a non-linear two-sided lobster group?

The braid group $B_{n}$ can be endowed with a left linear ordering (the Dehornoy ordering) and $PB_{n}$ can be endowed with a two-sided linear ordering (the Magnus ordering). Furthermore, the free group $F_{n}$ can be endowed with a non-linear left lobster ordering and the pure braid group $PB_{n}$ can be factored as a semidirect product $F_{n-1}\rtimes PB_{n-1}$. It therefore seems like it may be possible to make $B_{n}$ or $PB_{n}$ into at least a non-linear left lobster group.

Comment: Perhaps, just because they saw an undefined unknown (to them) notion in the very first line of the text?

Comment: That's crazy. If someone asks a question about unramified multipotent groups, and you don't know what they are, you shoud just ignore the question and leave it for someone who does know to answer. By downvoting you just reveal your ignorance.

Comment: @DerekHolt See https://mathoverflow.net/a/327619/ and the comments for some context (I have not voted on that answer or on this question)

Comment: Just to clarify: I neither voted on the question. I just tried to guess downvoter's feeling which (if guessed correctly) I share only partly.

Comment: Elaborating on Yemon Choi's comment, since the comments he refers to are now deleted: the OP suggested "lobster" as a term, it was observed that it was not in usage in that way, and the OP *then* asked this question and cited it as evidence to the contrary.

Comment: @NoahSchweber It sounds like you interpreted that the terminology motivated the question here but I see no reason to doubt that the question motivated the terminology.  (I don't have access to the comments you refer to).